# Command substitution and field splitting in shell

Tags: shell, posix

I understand why the following command fails.

```
$ a=foo bar
-bash: bar: command not found
```

It attempts to first execute `a=foo` and then execute `bar` which fails because there is no such command called `bar`.

But I don't understand why this works. I was expecting the following command to fail as well.

```
$ a=$(echo foo bar)
$ echo "$a"
foo bar
```

As per http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05 first command substitution happens, and then field splitting happens.

> **2.6 Word Expansions**
>
> This section describes the various expansions that are performed on
>   words. Not all expansions are performed on every word, as explained in
>   the following sections.
>
> Tilde expansions, parameter expansions, command substitutions,
>   arithmetic expansions, and quote removals that occur within a single
>   word expand to a single field. It is only field splitting or pathname
>   expansion that can create multiple fields from a single word. The
>   single exception to this rule is the expansion of the special
>   parameter '@' within double-quotes, as described in Special
>   Parameters.
>
> The order of word expansion shall be as follows:
>
> 1. Tilde expansion (see Tilde Expansion), parameter expansion (see Parameter Expansion), command substitution (see Command Substitution),
>      and arithmetic expansion (see Arithmetic Expansion) shall be
>      performed, beginning to end. See item 5 in Token Recognition.
> 2. Field splitting (see Field Splitting) shall be performed on the portions of the fields generated by step 1, unless IFS is null.
> 3. Pathname expansion (see Pathname Expansion) shall be performed, unless set -f is in effect.
> 4. Quote removal (see Quote Removal) shall always be performed last.

So after command subsitution,

```
a=$(echo foo bar)
```

becomes

```
a=foo bar
```

And then after to field splitting, `a=foo` should be executed first and then `bar` should be executed and then we should have the same error, i.e. `bar: command not found`. Why does `a=$(echo foo bar)` work fine then?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in [2.9.1 Simple Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) I believe.

Specifically points 1 and 4:

> 1. The words that are recognized as variable assignments or redirections according to Shell Grammar Rules are saved for processing in steps 3 and 4.
>
> 4. Each variable assignment shall be expanded for tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal prior to assigning the value.

Or in the bash reference manual in [3.4 Shell Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters):

> A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form
>
> name=[value]
>
> If value is not given, the variable is assigned the null string. All values undergo tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal (detailed below).

Comment: The key is that word-splitting does not occur in the  variable assignment. (That is, "word-splitting" does not appear in the list of expansions that are applied.)  In the example you give with `$(echo foo=bar)`, there is no variable assignment.  There is a process substitution which generates the string 'foo=bar', and that string is then treated as a simple command so the shell tries (and fails) to find a command named `foo=bar`

Comment: @WilliamPursell The question was *why* is it not applied there. Which, as I indicated and you reiterated, is because it isn't in the list of expansions done to assignments. Understanding how that applies here requires, I believe, the understanding of my latter point. Namely, that the initial token/word scanning is different than the expansions being discussed here. (Assuming I understand this situation clearly.)

Comment: William Pursell gave you the correct answer. However, if you want to understand better _why_ this happens, have a look at point 1 in the same section: `The words that are recognized as variable assignments or redirections according to Shell Grammar Rules are saved for processing in steps 3 and 4.` That means that the whole command substitution is _saved_ for later and point 4 tell you that no word splitting occurs.

Comment: @davidedb I'm not at all sure what the comment about correct answer was about but you are correct that point 1 is exactly the point I was trying to make in my last paragraph only written better.

Comment: @Etan Reisner: I was using my tablet and, because of the limited screen size and scrolling troubles, I erroneously thought you were the one asking the question. Sorry for any inconvenience.